# Wifi not being picked up

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi

I currently have a wifi usb dongle attached to my raspberry pi 1 model B, however it is not getting picked up.  I think that the wifi dongle is probably not supported but would like to just confirm.

I can see the pi pick up the USB when I run dmesg:

```
[    3.061377] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    3.073439] systemd[1]: Inserted module 'ipv6'
[    3.090634] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <raspberrypi>.
[    3.115947] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: register 'smsc95xx' at usb-20980000.usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet, b8:27:eb:5e:8d:a8
[    3.227388] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
[    3.322353] uart-pl011 20201000.uart: no DMA platform data
[    3.370245] random: systemd-sysv-ge: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 63 bits of entropy available)
[    3.397360] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0e8d, idProduct=7610
[    3.410517] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    3.423836] usb 1-1.2: Product: WiFi
[    3.433170] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: MediaTek
[    3.443483] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 1.0
[    3.587318] usb 1-1.3: new low-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
[    3.648243] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 65 bits of entropy available)
[    3.665961] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 65 bits of entropy available)
[    3.683745] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 65 bits of entropy available)
[    3.733949] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 67 bits of entropy available)
[    3.749839] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=413c, idProduct=2003
[    3.762602] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    3.775616] usb 1-1.3: Product: Dell USB Keyboard
[    3.785910] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: Dell
```

I can also see it whilst running the command lsusb:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 413c:2003 Dell Computer Corp. Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0e8d:7610 MediaTek Inc.
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9512 Standard Microsystems Corp. LAN9500 Ethernet 10/100 Adapter / SMSC9512/9514 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

and here is the lsmod output:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
cfg80211              500739  0
rfkill                 21397  1 cfg80211
evdev                  11650  1
snd_bcm2835            23131  0
snd_pcm                95473  1 snd_bcm2835
snd_timer              22556  1 snd_pcm
snd                    68400  3 snd_bcm2835,snd_timer,snd_pcm
bcm2835_gpiomem         3823  0
bcm2835_wdt             4133  0
uio_pdrv_genirq         3718  0
uio                    10230  1 uio_pdrv_genirq
ipv6                  367671  28
```

also here is my /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

#wifi network interface
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    #wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
    wireless-ssid [ssid]
    wireless-key [pass]

iface default inet dhcp
```

Answer (score 0):

The wifi dongle is being detected, but the driver is probably not present.

The output of `lsmod` shows that the normal WiFi module `cfg80211` is not being used by by devices.

You do not make life any easier for yourself by using non-standard settings (see [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) )
, although this does not appear to be your problem.